# Make visible a dropdown list and text box according to selection of a radio button

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I would like to display a dropdown list and text field according to the selection of a radio button in Yii form. ie, if I select the first option , it must display a dropdown list and if I select the second option the text box must appear.
This is the code for my radio button:

```
  <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'service_type',array('0'=>'Fixed Price Service','1'=>'Service at hourly rate'));?>
```

When selecting the "Fixed Price Service" the dropdown

`<?php echo $form->dropdownList( $model, 'min_budget', array(
                                                                                                                        "0"=>"Select your minimum budget",
                                                                                                                        "1" => "10000",
                                                                                                                        "2" => "20000",
                                                                                                                        "3" => "50000",
                                                                                                                      ));
                                                                                                 ?>`

and on selecting "Service at hourly rate" the text field must appear

```
 <?php echo $form->textField($model,'hourly_rate',array('size'=>15,'maxlength'=>1)); ?>
```

this function must appear without refreshing or clicking any submit buttons. How can I implement this in Yii form ?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript or jquery hide and show functions for this...
These links may help you

[display/hide textbox based on drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158737/display-hide-textbox-based-on-drop-down-list)

[jQuery - How to show/hide text box based on selected drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427495/jquery-how-to-show-hide-text-box-based-on-selected-drop-down)